# How to call a function in a backbone view from another backbone view

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

In my current application, I have a `save` function in one of my backbone views.

`custom_save : function() { 
// this method's save code
// have to call another views save function here
}`

The other view name is `App.SettingsView` and it has a `save` method. I have to call this `save` method right after the `custom_save` logic. How can I call `App.SettingsView save` function inside `custom_save` function. Please not both are 2 different files

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's a bad practice you got there. Coupling between the views. Why don't you create a EventBus that inherits from the `Backbone.Events` then trigger the event that the another  view subscribes too. When event occurs just trigger the save function that's it

**View#1 Save**

```
save:function(){
 EventBus.trigger("save:view");
}
```

**View#2 Save**

```
initialize:function(){
 EventBus.on("save:view:",this.save);
},
save:function(){
//your code
}
```

Sounds nice ? It should :)

Comment: do I have to add any new libraries for this, coz it gives me EventBus not defined error :(

Comment: @Mujahid `window.EventBus = Backbone.Events.extend({});` put this statement after document ready and before any statements that use this `eventBus`

Comment: Would you have a JSfiddle of this? I'm wondering if I need to define any more code for this to work... because it won't let me extend `Events`.

Comment: @Johannes Probably a error in the autocomplete of the IDE, try the code out tell me if you get a js error on the console

Comment: Yeah I figured it out, it was just a typo in your code where you has an extra colon.

Comment: :D Funny how it takes some time to get the philosophy of a technology :)

Comment: Noticed that if you have your app namespaced you can use underscore to extent the event bus `MyApp.EventBus = _.extend({}, Backbone.Events)` -- found here: http://spin.atomicobject.com/2012/04/16/lets-talk-an-eventbus-in-backbone-js/

Answer (score 3):

Create a new view object and call it.

```
var anotherView = new App.SettingView();
anotherView.save();
```

Comment: But when I create a `new App.SettingView()`  wont it call the `initialize()`?

Comment: Yes, it does. I am assuming you have some code in initialize that you don't want to trigger? One hacky way around it is to pass in an argument new App.Setting({execute: false}). However, Deeptechtons' solution is more elegance for sure :)